# How can an encryption scheme be indistinguishable with multiple messages but vulnerable to an adaptive chosen-plaintext attack?

Tags: encryption, chosen-plaintext-attack

In order to be indistinguishable with respect to multiple messages, wouldn't the scheme need to be nondeterministic? How would this then possibly be vulnerable to an adaptive CPA?

Comment: Are you asking if a cryptosystem that can withstand a non-adaptive chosen plaintext attack must also withstand an adaptive chosen plaintext attack?

Comment: Exactly -- though I'm really asking for an example rather than just a yes, as I'm aware that being able to withstand an adaptive CPA is theoretically more difficult than a non-adaptive one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you're asking about block ciphers.** Yes, it's possible.  Security against non-adaptive attacks does not imply security against adaptive attacks.  A simple example of a block cipher that is secure against non-adaptive attacks but insecure against adaptive attacks would be a random involution.  No, it doesn't need to be nondeterministic.

We say that a function $f:X\to X$ is an involution if $f$ is bijective and $f(f(x)) = x$ for all $x \in X$.  Suppose we have a block cipher $E:K \times X \to X$ where $E_k(\cdot)$ is an involution for all $k$.  Then $E$ is not secure against adaptive chosen-plaintext attack: an attacker can request the encryption of $x$, then request the encryption of that ciphertext, and check whether the result is equal to $x$.  However $E$ can be secure against non-adaptive chosen-plaintext attack.

An example construction of such a block cipher would be

$$E_k(x) = \text{AES-Decrypt}_k(\text{AES-Encrypt}_k(x) \oplus 1).$$

This is secure against non-adaptive chosen-plaintext attack (assuming that AES is secure) but insecure against adaptive chosen-plaintext attack.

**If you're asking about encryption schemes.** Yes, it's possible.  Security against non-adaptive attacks does not imply security against adaptive attacks.  It's easy to construct counterexamples.

For instance, consider the following encryption scheme.  To encrypt a message $m$ under key $k=(k_1,k_2)$, we first check whether $m=k_1$.  If $m \ne k_1$, then we pick $r$ randomly (subject to the constraint that $r\ne 0$) and output the ciphertext $c=(r,\text{AES}_{k_2}(r)\oplus m, k_1)$.  Otherwise, we output the ciphertext $c=(0,m,k_1)$.

This is a crazy-looking encryption scheme, but it is possible to show that it is secure against non-adaptive attacks: basically, it is just counter-mode encryption of a single-block message (since the attacker has no hope of guessing $k_1$).  However, this is completely insecure against adaptive attacks: an attacker who observes one ciphertext can learn $k_1$, from whence they can pose a chosen-plaintext message that lets them build a distinguishing attack.

Comment: Hm, but if a scheme isn't probabilistic, then any given plaintext will consistently result in a specific ciphertext, failing indistinguishability in the multiple messages case as the pair of messages $1, 1$ will be clearly distinguishable from $0, 1$, right?